# How to process postgres queries in netbeans (from internal terminal)?

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

I am having PostgreSQL source code compiled in netbeans. Now I've to give query, for example, `dropdb sample` via terminal. There is a inner terminal in netbeans. How can we give query in netbeans, such that the compiled code will process the query?

I know to connect postgresql in netbeans as well as in terminal

If I am trying to debug dropdb executables of postgres, it is showing

```
dropdb: missing required argument database name
Try "dropdb --help" for more information
```

dropdb query requires dbname to be processed.

How can I input this dbname via internal terminal of netbeans

Comment: `dropdb` is a **commandline** tool, not a SQL statement. Why don't you use `drop database` through JDBC?

Comment: Ya. I need to use the same command line tool dropdb via internal terminal of netbeans. Why cant I use that?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a command line tool? If you want to do it in your "compiled" code using JDBC and a SQL statement will be **much** easier then trying to run an external process.

Comment: No actually I am trying to find the flow of the available source code. I know how to use the code from terminal. But in case of netbeans, I dont know how to give these values as input

Comment: How can we use postgresql server in jdbc connectivity in netbeans? Is that option available?

Comment: You do that like any other JDBC connection. Please see the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: To access a database through the SQL client in NetBeans see the NetBeans manual: https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/work_dbases.htm#NBDAG1790

Comment: For java source codes only, this could work right? But this source package is c/c++.

Comment: Is there any way to do from internal terminal?